# Call reject that does not roll to voice mail

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, call-screening

I have been getting lots of calls (one per day) from the same number. There is never anyone on the other end. I placed the number in my 'call reject' list. Now my phone never rings when that number calls. Unfortunately it rolls over to voice mail and leaves an empty message. Now I need to go to voice mail to delete that message so that my voice mail indicator is cleared. How can I reject a call AND prevent the "caller" from leaving a voice mail?

At this point it is quicker for me to press "answer" then "disconnect".

Comment: There are some [Call Blocker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_various#group_97)s which do exactly that (answer, hang up). I just can't remember which ones that were. So if an app would be acceptable, see [Where to ask for app recommendations?](http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) for a fitting place (and how to put it).